# Tab sliding out - how to make it animate (move) a little on hover?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I'm using this [tabSlideOut jQuery plugin](http://www.building58.com/examples/tabSlideOut.html) in order to create a sliding tab. It works as intended.
However, I would like to add a behaviour where the slider slides in a little bit when hovering the tab.

I have tried to add an animation on hover like this:

```
$("#contactTab").hover(function() {
    $("#contactContainer").stop(true, true).animate({
        "right": "+=45px"
    }, 300);
}, function() {
    $("#contactContainer").stop(true, true).animate({
        "right": "-=45px"
    }, 300);
});
```

- but it comes out a little shaky...
[Fiddle here](http://jsbin.com/AGAZEhe/1).

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace #contactTab by #contactContainer:

```
  $("#contactContainer").hover(function() {
     $("#contactContainer").stop(true, true).animate({
          "right": "+=45px"
      }, 300); }, function() {
      $("#contactContainer").stop(true, true).animate({
          "right": "-=45px"
      }, 300); });
```

The problem with your code is the fact that each time the mouse moves outside of the A element, the block starts to slide back to its place. So when the mouse moves inside the white div, the block starts to slide back.

By moving the event onto the global div, the problem disappears.

Comment: OMG, that's almost embarrassing. :-) Works perfectly, thanks.